# What is the fourth moment of a Euclidean Norm?

Tags: expected-value, matrix, moments, norm

Let $X=\lVert M^\top p\rVert_2$, where $M$ is an $n\times n$ non-random matrix and $p\sim N(0,I_{n\times n})$ is an $n\times 1$ vector, and$\lVert \cdot\rVert_2$ is the Euclidean norm.

Using some linear algebra, we can determine that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X^2]=tr(MM^\top),
\end{equation}
where $tr(.)$ is the trace operator.

Now suppose instead we are interested in the 4th moment - i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X^4],
\end{equation}
How can this be obtained? For instance, is there an extension of Isserlis' Theorem which is appropriate in this setting?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/618796.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[X^4] &= E[X^2X^2] \\
&= \text{Cov}(X^2,X^2) + E[X^2]^2 \\
&= \text{Var}(X^2) + E[X^2]^2
\end{align}
Note that $X^2 = \| M^T p \|_2^2 = p^T M M^T p$, which follows a [generalized chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution) when $p\sim N(0,I_{n\times n})$. [Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Variance_in_the_Gaussian_case),
\begin{align}
E[X^4] &= \text{Var}(X^2) + E[X^2]^2 \\
&= 2\text{Tr}\left[MM^TMM^T\right] + \text{Tr}\left[MM^T\right]^2
\end{align}